# How do you control the output window of an Emacs Lisp shell command?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Given something like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") (lambda () (interactive) (shell-command "gcc --version")))
```

Is there a way to get the output to always go into a "new or existing window on the right" versus sometimes doing that, and sometimes putting the output in a little window below the status and command areas (two different possibilities shown below)?

[image]

Comment: The behaviour is: when the output is short, display it with echo area, otherwise, display the buffer which contains the output.

Comment: @xuchunyang While this is essentially true the behaviour is a bit more complicated. See help of `shell-command`. It is controlled by the variables `resize-mini-windows` and `max-mini-window-height`. Pityingly, `let`-ting `resize-mini-windows` to `nil` or  `resize-mini-windows` to `t` and  `max-mini-window-height` to zero does not solve the problem for one-line-outputs. Therefore, the somewhat complicated construction with `shell-command-to-string` in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works reliable also for one line of output (e.g. `"echo hello"` instead of `"gcc --version"`):

```elisp
(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                   (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*Shell Command Output*")
                     (erase-buffer)
                     (insert (shell-command-to-string "gcc --version"))
                     (display-buffer (current-buffer)))))
```